# Multiprocessing listener hangs on accept

Tags: python, connection, listener, python-multiprocessing

I don't understand why the listener hangs on the accept method. For example:

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

address = ('localhost', 6000) # tried other ports

listener = Listener(address, authkey=b'secret password')
conn = listener.accept() # gets stuck here
```

Comment: Because the socket is blocking and it waits until a connection from a client is present. Related https://bugs.python.org/issue32244.